# Insert image blob into google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, blob

Is it possible to insert an image blob into google spreadsheet?

Only found insertImage(url, column, row) in the SpreadSheet api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible in apps script. You can insert images only with public url. You may file a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry).

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the link to the issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3303)

Go ahead and click the star