# Exception: The blob format is unsupported. Google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, blob

I am running below code in google app script.

```
var data = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

var ssblob = Utilities.newBlob(data,"image/png","MyImage");

Logger.log(ssblob.getBytes().length);
Logger.log(ssblob.getName());

Logger.log(ssblob.getDataAsString());
Logger.log( ssblob.getContentType());

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.insertImage(ssblob,4,4);
```

Execution Log

5:34:37 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:34:37 PM  Info    116.0
5:34:37 PM  Info    MyImage
5:34:37 PM  Info    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
5:34:37 PM  Info    image/png
5:34:38 PM  Error
Exception: The blob format is unsupported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494230/insert-image-blob-into-google-spreadsheet

Comment: here are a couple fresh workarounds: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760259 (at the end)

Comment: They are providing solution from google drive or image url, where i have blob or raw data.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot provided the correct answer, but since he deleted it, I will post it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your data is base64 encoded
- `newBlob(data)` can only create a blob from a [byteArray](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata) or a [string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata_1)
- Thus, you need to convert your base64 encoded data to a byteArray first
- This can be done with [Utilities.base64Decode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64decodeencoded)

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var data = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
  let bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data);
  let ssblob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, "image/png", "yourImage");
  Logger.log(bytes.length);
  Logger.log(ssblob.getName());
  Logger.log(ssblob.getDataAsString());
  Logger.log( ssblob.getContentType());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.insertImage(ssblob,4,4);
}
```